# Using Columns As A Category Series In BIRT

Tags: sql

I currently have a select statement like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(CHECK_FORWARD.ID) AS CLOSED_SUMS
FROM CHECK_FORWARD
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(CHECK_RETURN.ID) AS CLOSED_SUMS
FROM CHECK_RETURN
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(CHECK_DEPOSIT.ID) AS CLOSED_SUMS
FROM CHECK_DEPOSIT
```

This returns a table like this

```
CLOSED_SUMS
-----------
1
1
21
```

I'm trying to create a BIRT PIE chart that shows the breakdown of those sums, but am lost as how to go about creating it. BIRT wants a category series (to categorize the sums).

Is there someway to use a computed column to create a list to create a table like:

```
CLOSED_SUMS    STATUS
-----------    ------
1              FORWARDED
1              RETURNED
21             DEPOSITED
```

I haven't been able to create an expression in the computed column expression wizard to return a column with all three Strings (i.e. "FORWARDED", "RETURNED", "DEPOSITED"). It just repeats one of the Strings for all of the values.

Should I be using an array to hold the value? And if so how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(CHECK_FORWARD.ID) AS CLOSED_SUMS, 'FORWARDED' AS STATUS
FROM CHECK_FORWARD
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(CHECK_RETURN.ID) AS CLOSED_SUMS, 'RETURNED' AS STATUS
FROM CHECK_RETURN
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(CHECK_DEPOSIT.ID) AS CLOSED_SUMS, 'DEPOSITED' AS STATUS
FROM CHECK_DEPOSIT
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting a hold of sql.